# How can I access the graph editor for keyframes on node values?

Tags: animation, node-editor, keyframes

I'm trying to get rid of the acceleration of the mapping node keyframe but I can't find where I can adjust it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a filter setting, in the graph editor. Most likely, you need to turn off *"only show selected"*, then you can choose the element types you want to see:

[image]